# How to determine if there are hidden columns when copying in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

As the title explains, I have an Excel 2003 workbook and I'm copying a number of columns of one sheet to another in VBA.  Unknown to me, someone has hidden a few columns on the source sheet and it has messed up how I process the cells in the destination sheet.

How can I programmically determine:

1. IF there are hidden columns
2. WHICH columns are hidden?

Thanks!
JFV

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a `Range`, check the [`Range.Hidden` property.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213533.aspx)

The following snippet from MSDN is a good example of how to hide/unhide a row/column:

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Hidden = True
```

You can also test the value with an `If` statement:

```
 For ColCounter = 1 To 10
      If Columns("C").Hidden = True Then
           Columns("C").Hidden = False
      End If
 Next
```

Comment: should also set some sort of a flag right in the conditional section where the col hidden is set to false... maybe an array where element 0 = col A, element 1 = col B and so forth

Comment: @Cheese: I just wanted to provide an example of how to iterate through and check the .Hidden states -- there are a great many ways to improve on the snippet (Using For Each Column instead of a counter, for instance).

Comment: @scag yeah i figured that... wasn't trying to bash you or anything, just was addressing the second part of his question - ps, your last name is very familiar... West Essex High School?  I'm from fairfield...

Comment: @Cheese my sister went there in the mid-90s

Comment: @A. Scagnelli: Thanks for the answer.  It bothered me when pasting it messed with the column order.  @CheeseConQueso: Thanks for the additional point to the answer, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to copy the visible files then one option that is quite nice it to select only the visible columns as a range.

This can be done by

```
Set visrng =rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

It wasn't clear to me if this would be useful in your case, but I decided to post it as it could be useful to others.

Comment: @Modan:  Thanks for the info.  Sounds like I might be able to incorporate that in the next version.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Copying Visible Cells to another Range and then comparing the number of cells in each is probably the easiest way to determine if there are Hidden Cells in the Range

eg

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=VisRan

If Not Selection.Cells.Count = VisRan.Cells.Count Then
    MsgBox "Selection contains Hidden Cells"
End If
```

Comment: Not bad, but I'd suggest leaving out the copy. `IF Not Range.Cells.Count = Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count`

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using a function like:

```
Function IsColumnHidden(column As Variant) as Boolean
    IsColumnHidden = False
    If Columns(column).ColumnWidth = 0.0 Then IsColumnHidden = True
End Function
```

A Column width or Row height of 0.0 is an indicator of whether or not the range is hidden.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one that I have tested and it works well if you want to hide/unhide columns

`Sub Macro1_Test_Hidden() ' ' Macro1_Test_Hidden Macro ' ' ' If Columns("BH:XFA").Hidden = False Then Columns("BH:XFA").Select Range("BH:XFA").Activate Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Else Columns("BH:XFA").Select Range("BH:XFA").Activate Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False End If ' ' End Sub`